# Armazenamento de dados em pasta local

Tags: javascript

Gente tenho este script que foi criado por um colega que não esta mais na ativa.O problema apesar de parecer que tudo esta certo tem alguma coisa errada e eu não consigo achar o que é. O objetivo dele é armazenar poucos dados de um formulário numa pasta criada no ato do preenchimento do mesmo. No caso o script deve alem de criar uma pasta deve permitir edição e deleção do conteúdo. Esse script foi feito para o internet explorer mas se alguém tiver uma ideia de um script que funcione no firefox seria melhor.

```
//Cria Objeto ActiveX
var dados = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

//Função para gravar o arquivo
function GravarArquivo (arq,texto){
//pasta a ser salvo o arquivo
var pasta = "C:\Users\Convidado\Desktop\teste";

//se o parametro arq que é o nome do arquivo vier vazio ele salvará o arquivo com o nome “Sem Titulo”
if(arq==""){arq="Sem Titulo";}
//carrega o txt
var esc = dados.CreateTextFile(pasta+arq+".txt", false);
//escreve o que foi passado no parametro texto que é o texto contido no TextArea
esc.WriteLine(texto);
//fecha o txt
esc.Colose();
}
//Função para abrir o arquivo
fuction AbreArquivo (arq){
//o parametro arq é o endereço do txt
//carrega o txt
var arquivo = dados.OpenTextFile(arq, 1, true);
//varre o arquivo
while(!arquivo.AtEndOfStream){
//escreve o txt no TextArea
document.getElementById("texto").value = arquivo.ReadAll();
}
//fecha o txt
arquivo.Close();
}
```

Comment: Esse script só irá funcionar em algumas versões do I.E. Browsers modernos não utilizam mais objetos ActiveX . Sugiro que os seus dados sejam gravados na local storage, irá funcionár em todos os browsers.

Comment: Você teria algum script com os predicados semelhantes a esse que eu postei mas que faça a gravação no local storage?

Comment: Tenho vários, mas você é perfeitamente capaz de escrevê-los sozinho. Esses 2 links em inglês explicam muito bem: [Arquivo do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) e [outro artigo](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). Esse artigo é da DEVMEDIA e está em português: [link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-html5-local-storage-e-json/29045)

Comment: Se você desejar seguinto por esse caminho (ActiveX), existem outros plugins para outros browser que habilitam ActiveX, com relação ao erro, verifique no console qual erro está ocorrendo com seu código e poste junto com a pergunta. Eu recomendo a localStorage pois além de ser multiplataforma é um idioma comum para armazenamento persistente

Comment: Valeu. Vou dar uma olhada e se tiver duvidas eu posto aqui.